# Maas custom curtin config failure on clearing disks at deployment stage

Tags: maas, mdadm

I've upgraded Maas to 2.7 and now we have this problem:

```
Detected holders during mdadm creation: ['md127']
        An error occured handling 'mddevice0': OSError - [Errno Failed to remove holders from %s] /dev/sda2
        finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: FAIL: configuring raid: mddevice0
        TIMED BLOCK_META: 21.036
        finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: FAIL: curtin command block-meta
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/main.py", line 202, in main
            ret = args.func(args)
          File "/curtin/curtin/log.py", line 97, in wrapper
            return log_time("TIMED %s: " % msg, func, *args, **kwargs)
          File "/curtin/curtin/log.py", line 79, in log_time
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 86, in block_meta
            return meta_custom(args)
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 1677, in meta_custom
            handler(command, storage_config_dict)
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 1157, in raid_handler
            mdadm.mdadm_create(md_devname, raidlevel,
          File "/curtin/curtin/block/mdadm.py", line 177, in mdadm_create
            raise OSError('Failed to remove holders from %s', device)
        OSError: [Errno Failed to remove holders from %s] /dev/sda2
        [Errno Failed to remove holders from %s] /dev/sda2
```

We have this configured in storage section of custom curtin config:

```
storage:
  version: 1
  config:
    - id: {{bootdevice1}}
      type: disk
      ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/{{bootdevice1}}
      name: boot_drive_1
      grub_device: 1
      wipe: superblock-recursive
    - id: bios_boot_partition_1
      type: partition
      size: 1MB
      device: {{bootdevice1}}
      flag: bios_grub
    - id: {{bootdevice1}}2
      type: partition
      size: 32000000000B
      device: {{bootdevice1}}
    - id: {{bootdevice1}}3
      type: partition
      size: 20000000000B
      device: {{bootdevice1}}
    - id: {{bootdevice1}}4
      type: partition
      size: 20000000000B
      device: {{bootdevice1}}
    - id: {{bootdevice1}}5
      type: partition
      size: 20000000000B
      device: {{bootdevice1}}
    - id: {{bootdevice1}}6
      type: partition
      size: 20000000000B
      device: {{bootdevice1}}
{{if node.get_bios_boot_method() == 'uefi'}}
    - id: {{bootdevice1}}7
      type: partition
      size: 512MB
      device: {{bootdevice1}}
      flag: boot
    - id: fs_efi_boot1
      type: format
      fstype: fat32
      volume: {{bootdevice1}}7
{{endif}}
```

Shouldn't wipe: superblock-recursive erased all before trying to create partition?

I think that problem is that old md arrays were started and not stopped before deploy, hense failure to wipe superblocks, but should Maas do it by itself or I have to add some early commands or partition stage commands to stop it? Also I've used release with disk erase but that didn't help either (well I've used quick erase, but still)